# cannot stat: Filename too long on GIT PULL

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am getting the below error while pulling changes from a GIT branch
....

> cannot stat 'somelongfilename.sql': Filename too long

c
As a solution, I am trying to add `longpaths = true` to gitconfig file. This is located in the system default folder and I do not have permission to edit this file.

I am looking for a quick solution here. Is there any other way I can resolve this issue instead of editing gitconfig file?

Comment: configure it in the repo's `.git/config` (or with `git config` **without** `--global`).

Comment: I dont see this folder in my repo @eftshift0

Comment: You mean.... `.git`? That's what makes git tic. I guess you are looking into a subdirectory, or a subtree. Run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` where the repo is located and then check `some-repo-dir/.git/config`

Answer (score 13):

I solved the issue with the below command

Used

```bash
git config --global core.longpaths true
```

instead of

```bash
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Answer (score 1):

`git` takes [the `-c` option](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git/2.10.5#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt) to set a configuration option for the command. For example `git -c core.longpaths=true pull ...` should enable `core.longpaths=true` for the duration of the `pull` command.

Note, however, that you still need to set the [system-level requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry) to enable long paths on Windows before `git` can take advantage of them.